# Not getting any movement from sprite in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, sprite-kit, sprite

I am trying to move a sprite node down every time I touch in a certain area. This is the code I have and the log is showing that the touches register. What am I doing wrong and is there an easier way to accomplish this?

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    CGPoint currentLocation = [currentTouch locationInView:currentTouch.view];

    if (currentLocation.y > 500) {


    CGFloat newY = _bg.position.y - 25;
    _bg.position = CGPointMake(_bg.position.x, newY);
    NSLog(@"touchtouch");
}
```

Comment: is _bg non-nil? set a breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

if (currentLocation.y > 500) {


    CGFloat newY = _bg.position.y - 25;
    _bg.position = CGPointMake(_bg.position.x, newY);
    NSLog(@"touchtouch");
      }
   }
}
```

You can also use an `SKAction` to have the movement animated:

```
SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveToY:newY duration:1];
    [_bg runAction:moveDown];
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I'm still not getting any movement from the sprite. What could be preventing it?

Comment: Make sure you use the right values for example if you really want the .y to be higher than 500